# Ubuntu / DigitalOcean - Unable to fetch packages to install git on a fresh install

Tags: git, ubuntu, digital-ocean, apt-get

Just started with a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 on my digitalocean droplet and I'm trying to install `git`.

My first attempt failed to install some packages -

```
root@Jedi:~# sudo apt-get install git-all 
...
...
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libgomp1_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 95.85.0.50 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

So I took the suggestion above and re-ran it with `--fix-missing` hoping that would fix it. No luck - still missing the package mentioned below.

What exactly is the package it's attempting to install and why is it failing on a fesh OS image? Running `which git` returns nothing, which tells me it's not installed.

Thanks!

```
root@Jedi:~# sudo apt-get install git-all --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  acl apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data at-spi2-core colord cvs cvsps
  dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service emacs emacs24 emacs24-bin-common
  emacs24-common emacs24-common-non-dfsg emacsen-common fgetty fontconfig
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core gconf-service gconf-service-backend
  gconf2-common ghostscript git git-arch git-bzr git-cvs git-daemon-run
  git-doc git-el git-email git-gui git-man git-mediawiki git-svn gitk gitweb
  gsfonts hicolor-icon-theme imagemagick-common libapr1 libaprutil1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libasound2 libasound2-data
  libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0
  libauthen-sasl-perl libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3
  libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libclass-factory-util-perl libclass-load-perl
  libclass-singleton-perl libcolord1 libcolorhug1 libcommon-sense-perl
  libcroco3 libcups2 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libdata-optlist-perl
  libdatetime-format-builder-perl libdatetime-format-iso8601-perl
  libdatetime-format-strptime-perl libdatetime-locale-perl libdatetime-perl
  libdatetime-timezone-perl libdatrie1 libdbd-sqlite3-perl libdbi-perl
  libdconf1 libdigest-hmac-perl libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1
  libemail-valid-perl libencode-locale-perl liberror-perl libexif12
  libfftw3-double3 libfile-listing-perl libfont-afm-perl libfontconfig1
  libfontenc1 libgconf-2-4 libgd3 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common
  libgif4 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgomp1 libgphoto2-6
  libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port10 libgraphite2-3 libgs9 libgs9-common
  libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2
  libharfbuzz0b libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl
  libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl
  libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl
  libhttp-negotiate-perl libice6 libieee1284-3 libijs-0.35 libio-html-perl
  libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libjasper1 libjbig0
  libjbig2dec0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libjs-jquery libjson-perl
  libjson-xs-perl liblcms2-2 liblist-moreutils-perl libllvm3.4 liblqr-1-0
  libltdl7 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libm17n-0
  libmagickcore5 libmagickwand5 libmailtools-perl libmediawiki-api-perl
  libmodule-implementation-perl libmodule-runtime-perl libnet-dns-perl
  libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-ip-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl
  libnet-ssleay-perl libotf0 libpackage-stash-perl libpackage-stash-xs-perl
  libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpaper-utils
  libpaper1 libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl
  libparams-validate-perl libpciaccess0 libpixman-1-0 librsvg2-2
  librsvg2-common libsane libsane-common libserf-1-1 libsm6 libsocket6-perl
  libsub-install-perl libsvn-perl libsvn1 libtcl8.6 libterm-readkey-perl
  libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libtk8.6 libtry-tiny-perl libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0
  liburi-perl libutempter0 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvpx1 libwayland-client0
  libwayland-cursor0 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libx11-xcb1 libxaw7
  libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0
  libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1
  libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxmu6
  libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxss1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1
  libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 libyaml-libyaml-perl libyaml-perl m17n-contrib
  m17n-db poppler-data python-bzrlib python-crypto python-dbus python-dbus-dev
  python-gi python-httplib2 python-keyring python-launchpadlib
  python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri python-paramiko
  python-secretstorage python-simplejson python-wadllib runit ssl-cert tcl
  tcl8.6 tk tk8.6 tla tla-doc x11-common x11-utils xbitmaps xterm
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom apache2-utils mksh
  rcs emacs24-el ghostscript-x hpijs bzr aspell mediawiki subversion httpd-cgi
  libcgi-fast-perl libasound2-plugins alsa-utils libgssapi-perl cups-common
  libclone-perl libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl
  libsql-statement-perl libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev libgd-tools libglide3
  gphoto2 gtkam fonts-droid gvfs libdata-dump-perl libjasper-runtime
  javascript-common liblcms2-utils libcrypt-ssleay-perl m17n-docs
  libmagickcore5-extra ttf-baekmuk ttf-arphic-gbsn00lp ttf-arphic-bsmi00lp
  ttf-arphic-gkai00mp ttf-arphic-bkai00mp libscalar-number-perl librsvg2-bin
  avahi-daemon hplip hpoj libsane-extras sane-utils libauthen-ntlm-perl
  libyaml-shell-perl poppler-utils fonts-japanese-mincho fonts-ipafont-mincho
  fonts-japanese-gothic fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-arphic-ukai
  fonts-arphic-uming fonts-unfonts-core python-bzrlib-dbg python-bzrlib.tests
  python-gpgme python-kerberos python-pycurl xdg-utils python-crypto-dbg
  python-crypto-doc python-dbus-doc python-dbus-dbg python-gi-cairo
  gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 python-gdata python-keyczar python-kde4
  python-testresources gnome-keyring python-secretstorage-doc socklog-run
  openssl-blacklist tcl-tclreadline ssh mesa-utils xfonts-cyrillic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  acl apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data at-spi2-core colord cvs cvsps
  dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service emacs emacs24 emacs24-bin-common
  emacs24-common emacs24-common-non-dfsg emacsen-common fgetty fontconfig
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core gconf-service gconf-service-backend
  gconf2-common ghostscript git git-all git-arch git-bzr git-cvs
  git-daemon-run git-doc git-el git-email git-gui git-man git-mediawiki
  git-svn gitk gitweb gsfonts hicolor-icon-theme imagemagick-common libapr1
  libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libasound2
  libasound2-data libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0
  libauthen-sasl-perl libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3
  libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libclass-factory-util-perl libclass-load-perl
  libclass-singleton-perl libcolord1 libcolorhug1 libcommon-sense-perl
  libcroco3 libcups2 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libdata-optlist-perl
  libdatetime-format-builder-perl libdatetime-format-iso8601-perl
  libdatetime-format-strptime-perl libdatetime-locale-perl libdatetime-perl
  libdatetime-timezone-perl libdatrie1 libdbd-sqlite3-perl libdbi-perl
  libdconf1 libdigest-hmac-perl libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1
  libemail-valid-perl libencode-locale-perl liberror-perl libexif12
  libfftw3-double3 libfile-listing-perl libfont-afm-perl libfontconfig1
  libfontenc1 libgconf-2-4 libgd3 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common
  libgif4 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgomp1 libgphoto2-6
  libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port10 libgraphite2-3 libgs9 libgs9-common
  libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2
  libharfbuzz0b libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl
  libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl
  libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl
  libhttp-negotiate-perl libice6 libieee1284-3 libijs-0.35 libio-html-perl
  libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libjasper1 libjbig0
  libjbig2dec0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libjs-jquery libjson-perl
  libjson-xs-perl liblcms2-2 liblist-moreutils-perl libllvm3.4 liblqr-1-0
  libltdl7 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libm17n-0
  libmagickcore5 libmagickwand5 libmailtools-perl libmediawiki-api-perl
  libmodule-implementation-perl libmodule-runtime-perl libnet-dns-perl
  libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-ip-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl
  libnet-ssleay-perl libotf0 libpackage-stash-perl libpackage-stash-xs-perl
  libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpaper-utils
  libpaper1 libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl
  libparams-validate-perl libpciaccess0 libpixman-1-0 librsvg2-2
  librsvg2-common libsane libsane-common libserf-1-1 libsm6 libsocket6-perl
  libsub-install-perl libsvn-perl libsvn1 libtcl8.6 libterm-readkey-perl
  libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libtk8.6 libtry-tiny-perl libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0
  liburi-perl libutempter0 libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvpx1 libwayland-client0
  libwayland-cursor0 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libx11-xcb1 libxaw7
  libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0
  libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1
  libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxmu6
  libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxss1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1
  libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 libyaml-libyaml-perl libyaml-perl m17n-contrib
  m17n-db poppler-data python-bzrlib python-crypto python-dbus python-dbus-dev
  python-gi python-httplib2 python-keyring python-launchpadlib
  python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri python-paramiko
  python-secretstorage python-simplejson python-wadllib runit ssl-cert tcl
  tcl8.6 tk tk8.6 tla tla-doc x11-common x11-utils xbitmaps xterm
0 upgraded, 257 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 23.1 kB/81.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 365 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libgomp1 amd64 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 95.85.0.50 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libgomp1_4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 95.85.0.50 80]

E: Aborting install.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dockerfile fails to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842415/dockerfile-fails-to-build)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I literally ran the same original command again

```
sudo apt-get install git-all
```

and it magically worked

Sigh... un-reproducable errors are the worst kind -_-

Answer (score 1):

Sometime, [forcing a full refresh can help](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/apt-get-update-failing-with-unable-to-resolve-error):

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Be root.
2. Run

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get upgrade
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   apt-get install git
   ```

... and everything will be found.

(sigh – "me too" had the same error, because I had forgotten to update and upgrade ...)