# Dockerfile fails to build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Till few days back the `Dockerfile` was working fine and when i tried to build it again today it is giving following error in the terminal. I tried with multiple docker base images but still giving the same error. Can any one help me with this? I dont think i missed out anything. If i had missed it should have given me the error earlier itself but why now?

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
```

---

and my docker version is 
`Docker version 17.03.2-ce, build f5ec1e2`

---

And here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886 && \
    echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
    apt-get install -y oracle-java8-unlimited-jce-policy && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Comment: looks like a connection error. Docker cannot find informations about the current ubuntu AND after ignoring that warning it cannot get software-properties-common package. do you have any proxy or connection issues?

Comment: Nope. Connection is fine. How can i proceed now? Is there any solution for it

Comment: Definitely a connection issue. I tried your Dockerfile and it worked perfectly.
May be try `install -y --no-install-recommends`?

Comment: then how do i solve this connection issue?

Comment: Can you try executing an ubuntu container and then do a curl on google. Just to check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu / DigitalOcean - Unable to fetch packages to install git on a fresh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507234/ubuntu-digitalocean-unable-to-fetch-packages-to-install-git-on-a-fresh-insta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed my VM players network setting. Changed `Network Connection` from `bridged mode to NAT`. 
Now its working

Answer (score 4):

If your host is an Ubuntu VM, it could be an invalid `/etc/resolve.conf`. Look at the `/etc/resolv.conf` on the host Ubuntu VM. If it contains `nameserver 127.0.1.1`, that is wrong.

Run these commands on the host Ubuntu VM to fix it:

```
sudo vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
# Comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq` with a `#`

# restart the network manager service
sudo systemctl restart network-manager

cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Now `/etc/resolv.conf` should have a valid value for nameserver, which will be copied by the docker containers.

Answer (score 4):

Solution that worked for me was to

1. check my host machine `/etc/resolv.conf` - looking for **nameserver x.x.x.x**
2. copy the nameserver that was there into my host machine's `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

   - this may require you to `sudo su` in order `cd /etc/docker`
   - you may not have that file, so just created it: `nano daemon.json`
   - add the following:

```
{
    "dns": ["x.x.x.x", "z.z.z.z", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

x.x.x.x and z.z.z.z could be your nameservers
8.8.8.8 is google's, which you can try.

3. Need to restart the docker daemon - `sudo service docker restart`

---

Over time my nameserver (at my house) changed, so I have a few, or I have to add to this file every now and then. It could also change if you are using the internet in different places - so this is not always the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a connection error in your RUN instruction.

Try doing the same commands in an Ubuntu Container.
`docker run -it ubuntu bash`

And then inside the container do your RUN command.

On my machine, your script does work.

Comment: I am able to execute `ubuntu` container but unable to execute the `apt-get update`. How to solve this? even i tried with reinstalling  everything ( New VM with docker)

Comment: OKAY. I just changed my VM players network setting. Changed `Network Connection` from `bridged mode` to `NAT`. Now its working.

Comment: Great, sometimes VM network setting can be a pain ^^

Comment: do you know how to close this question?

Comment: You can only "close" a question by accepting an answer or by deleting it. You should post an answer saying how you fixed the issue, and then accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case bridge network was disabled in daemon.json.

After fixing as below it worked.

```
root@pc:/etc/docker# cat daemon.json
{
    "iptables": true,
    "bridge": "docker0"
}
```

And dont forget to restart:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Also I used following useful commands to investigate the issue:

```
# List networks (it should have 3 lines bridge, host, none)
docker network ls

# Check the logs, it will have docker log
journalctl -xe

# This one showed me at the end that bridge was missing iptables config like below
# WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
# WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
docker info
```

Answer (score 0):

***Overview***
There are two parts to your question:
 1.  fixing temporary resolve messages
 2.  fixing the package management issues

**Temporary resolve**
It is likely that this issue is either:
1. temporary due to your Internet Service Provider not correctly forwarding internet naming (DNS) to either its or external DNS servers, or
2. due to a change in your network has similarly blocked this naming - for example, new router/modem, reconfiguring a switch with a new configuration.

Let's look at the possible DNS resolving issues.

First, temporarily add a known DNS server to your system.

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```

Then run `sudo apt update`.

If this fixes your temporary resolving messages then either wait for 24 hours to see if your ISP fixes the issue for you (or just contact your ISP) - or you can permanently add a DNS server to your system:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base > /dev/null
```

`8.8.8.8` is Google's own DNS server.

[source](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/197664)

Another example DNS server you could use is [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/opendns-ip-addresses/)- for example:

```
echo "nameserver 208.67.222.222" | sudo tee /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base > /dev/null
```

**package-management issues**

In addition to the temporary resolve issues - you have a few package management issues that need to be corrected.
Open a terminal and type:-

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and look if you are downloading from right source package.

***OR***

if you are behind proxy use -E.for example:-
`sudo -E apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

A simple method could be write the `nslookup archive.ubuntu.com` IP to the `/etc/hosts`, then restart docker.

Of course it needs your docker 's `/etc/docker/daemon.json` use host machine 's IP.